# Multer Error: Image url is not save in my Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

At first i met Multer: Unexpected field error, after i fixed until here. every boards column is save in DB except image. is my postman test method is wrong? or my code have problem? how can i save image url(path) in boards image column?

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, done) {
      done(null, "uploads/");
    },
    filename(req, file, done) {
      const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
      const basename = path.basename(file.originalname, ext);
      done(null, basename + new Date().getTime() + ext);
    },
  }),
  limits: { fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 }, // 5MB
});

router.post("/images", upload.single("image"), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ url: `/uploads/${req.file.filename}` });
});

router.post("/", upload.single("image"), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {
      category,
      title,
      description,
      tags,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      mainAddress,
      detailAddress,
    } = req.body;
    const createBoards = await boards.create({
      category,
      title,
      description,
      tags,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      mainAddress,
      detailAddress,
      image: req.body.url,
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ data: createBoards, message: "OK" });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Error"});
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaFnn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cBKY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYygx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `url` you mean the actual path multer has assigned for your uploaded file, you can use the property `path` on the `file` object. See [this](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) for all available properties.

So in your case you can do:

```
const createBoards = await boards.create({
      category,
      title,
      description,
      tags,
      latitude,
      longitude,
      mainAddress,
      detailAddress,
      image: req.file.path // to be safe you should maybe add a check if req.file is defined
    });
```